# what is the purpose of verifying user response on server side in recaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha

I can't understand why I need to validate user response on server side in `recaptcha v2`? Is just checking on client side sufficient? I suspect that server side validation is also important as otherwise `recaptcha` is just a `checkbox`.

Which bring me to my other question - How is `recaptcha` not different from just a `checkbox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't understand why I need to validate user response on server side in recaptcha v2?

An attacker could make an HTTP request to your server-side code that completely bypasses all your client-side code, including the CAPTCHA.

> How is recaptcha not different from just a checkbox?

It applies a large collection of heuristics measured with JavaScript and then generates a custom value.

It isn't a simple true/false that can be determined just by scraping a page.